# StreamTcpException while under server stress

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have a service using Akka HTTP that I have been doing some load testing on. Under stress, I've found that my service will ocassionally run into StreamTcpException when calling other service endpoints.

I create one flow for each endpoint which is shared by all of my actors. I am using something like this:

```
//this is done only once
val connectionFlow = Http(sys).outgoingConnection("host_name")

...

//each actor does this
val response = Source.single(HttpRequest(...)).via(connectionFlow).runWith(Sink.head)
```

I use Apache JMeter to load test my service, and with 40 threads, it typically takes 2000-4000 requests before I see my first error message. With 10 threads, it took me 9000 requests before I saw it.

The message looks like: 
`akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(<host_here>/<ip_here>,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed`

I actually have 4 separate flows for 4 different endpoints my service relies on. I usually see StreamTcpException from all four if my service fails.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the message from the StreamTcpException?

Comment: @johanandren `akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(<host_here>/<ip_here>,None,List(),Some(10 seconds),true)] failed`

Comment: Hm, that didn't help much I'm afraid. Have you tried turning on debug logging to see if that gives any further insights? (The interesting stuff should come from the TcpOutgoingConnection actor)

Comment: @johanandren Yeah it's a pretty vague error message unfortunately. I just turned on debug logging, but I don't see anything coming from TcpOutgoingConnection when I receive the error (maybe I did something wrong?).

Comment: It's possible that you have run out of available ports locally as they are not being recycled fast enough. Have you considered a host connection pool instead a new connection for every outbound request?  That should reduce port churn and be far more efficient for a high load scenario like this.

Answer (score -1):

I face same issue previously, for me it is working as expected.

```
val httpClient: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]] = Http().outgoingConnection(host,port,None,connSetts)
```

Problem place  `Source.single(request).via(httpClient)`

It is unable to connect my host so I use proxy server for this.

```
val httpsProxyTransport : ClientTransport = ClientTransport.httpsProxy(InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("proxyservicesHost", 90))
val connSetts: ClientConnectionSettings = ClientConnectionSettings(system).withTransport(httpsProxyTransport).withIdleTimeout(Duration(180, "second"))
val httpClient: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]] = Http().outgoingConnection(host,port,None,connSetts)
```

Then I pass the `httpclient` in `.via(httpclient)`, it works.